# Remove leading and trailing slash / in python

Tags: python, django, path, strip

I am using `request.path`  to return the current URL in Django, and it is returning  `/get/category`.

I need it as `get/category` (without leading and trailing slash).

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you not want the leading slash?

Comment: This is used as ***an example*** in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420159/poor-sorting-of-answers). That is, not the subject of.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
>>> "/get/category".strip("/")
'get/category'
```

`strip()` is the proper way to do this.

Comment: strip() will also take care of multiple "/"'s

Comment: Note also the existence of `lstrip()` and `rstrip()`, in case you want to e.g. remove trailing slashes but preserve leading ones.

Comment: Actually, I think you should use `strip(os.sep)`

Comment: For filesystem paths, `os.path.normpath(*path*)` will strip trailing slashes.

Comment: @EdwardFalk that would break if the server is Windows. The context here is URLs.

Answer (score 20):

```
def remove_lead_and_trail_slash(s):
    if s.startswith('/'):
        s = s[1:]
    if s.endswith('/'):
        s = s[:-1]
    return s
```

Unlike `str.strip()`, this is guaranteed to remove at most one of the slashes on each side.

Answer (score 8):

Another one with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "/get/category"
>>> re.sub("^/|/$", "", s)
'get/category'
```