# How to remove trailing Slash in django URL in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Please note this is a Django issue and `APPEND_SLASH = False` does not work either. This is not a duplicate question as suggested. I need to do this inside the template.

How do you remove the ending slash in Django URLs so you can make href links to jump on sections of a webpage? If you have

```
a href="#section1"
```

And a url `www.domain1.com/index`, django makes it `www.domain1.com/index/` so you get `www.domain1.com/index/#secton1` when it should be `www.domain1.com/index#section1`.

Does anybody know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove leading and trailing slash /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408826/remove-leading-and-trailing-slash)

Comment: Need remove inside Template, not a duplicate question.

Comment: why not you make your custom template tag?

Comment: how do you generate urls inside the template?

Comment: any built in filter or tags in Django?

Comment: @djangodeveloper what code are you using to get the in page url's?

Comment: Need to see the template code.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, If anyone is still looking for the answer -

In your HTML:

```
{% url 'index' as temporary_url %}
<a href="{{ temporary_url|slice:':-1' }}#secton1"> Link </a>
```