# Django URL matching a trailing slash

Tags: python, django, url, matching

If I add to my urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [url(r'^(\S+)$', views.myview, name='myview') ]
```

I expect it to match "mysite.com/anything/" but it does not.  Navigating to that URL in my browser adds "Not Found: /anything/" to my "error.log".  It only appears to match URLs that do NOT end with "/".  Why?

I tried explicitly adding the slash at the end

```
urlpatterns += [url(r'^(\S+)/$', views.myview, name='myview') ]
```

but still no match to "mysite.com/anything/"

The only way I can get a match is to avoid using the \S+.  This matches:

```
urlpatterns += [url(r'^anything/$', views.myview, name='myview') ]
```

but defeats the purpose of the \S+ and what I want to do.

Comment: '''APPEND_SLASH                             = True''' in settings.py might help or please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408826/remove-leading-and-trailing-slash-in-python

Comment: My issue is that I can't match URLs ending with "/".  APPEND_SLASH was true.  Interestingly, if I set it to False Django won't match any URL, with or without a "/" at the end.

Comment: please try:  ```urlpatterns += [url(r'^.+/$', views.myview, name='myview') ]```